Is there any logs for "kubectl create token <sa>" in gcp log explorer?
I try to find the logs when I use "kubectl create token " command in GKE environment.
I type this command in GCP console directly.
But I can not find any logs to record what I did in GCP log explorer.
I try to use many specific pattern to find the logs:

user-agent
specific ip address
the service account name which I create token
try to guess the pattern (eg. protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.token.create")
my email name

I also check I enable all the audit logs setting in gcp environment.
Sadly, I can not find any logs when I use "create token" command.
Anyone knows how I can get the logs? Thanks!!

Ok, I know the answer.
You should go to the gcp k8s cluster setting page.
Then, finding the options named "logging".
Next, click the pencil icon.
Finally, adding the API Server options.
Now, you can find the create token logs.
